# Sum 2 columns and combine rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Primary key is a combination of `reportdate,market,platform`.
If I get 2 or multiple records I want to sum the `impr` and `leads` column for row_num = 1 and delete row_num = 2 (I figured the delete part, but still trying the sum part).

How to sum `impr` and `leads` column to get the desired output as below.

These are my input records:

```
reportdate      market  platform    impr            leads   create_date       file_id   row_num
2020-05-16      TX      quote       0.00000         7.00000     2020-06-11      11345   1
2020-05-16      TX      quote       600.00000       0.00000     2020-06-11      11345   2
2020-05-16      CA      street      50.00000        0.00000     2020-06-11      11345   1
2020-05-16      CA      street       0.00000        4.00000     2020-06-11      11345   2
2020-05-16      PA      unknown     0.00000         7.00000     2020-06-11      11345   1
2020-05-16      PA      unknown     600.00000       0.00000     2020-06-11      99999   2
```

I want to see records as my output:

```
reportdate      market  platform    impr            leads   create_date       file_id   row_num
2020-05-16      TX      quote       600.00000       7.00000     2020-06-11      11345   1
2020-05-16      CA      street      50.00000        4.00000     2020-06-11      11345   1
2020-05-16      PA      unknown     0.00000         7.00000     2020-06-11      11345   1
2020-05-16      PA      unknown     600.00000       0.00000     2020-06-11      99999   2
```

Comment: So, what have you got so far, and why isn't it working?

Comment: I'm lost.  If there is a primary key, then the data is not duplicated.  Are you saying that the input data is more detailed than you want and you want aggregation on insert?

Answer (score 0):

This is either aggregation, or window functions.

For your current dataset, aggregation is good enough:

```
select
    reportdate,
    market, 
    platform,
    sum(impr) impr,
    sum(leads) leads,
    create_date,
    file_id,
    min(row_num) row_num
from mytable
group by
    reportdate,
    market, 
    platform,
    create_date,
    file_id
```

If, on the other hand, you have varying values in columns such as `file_id` or `create_date` for a given `(reportdate, market, platform)` tuple, then you would need to use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        reportdate,
        market, 
        platform,
        sum(impr) over(partition by reportdate, market, platform) impr,
        sum(leads) over(partition by reportdate, market, platform) leads,
        create_date,
        file_id,
        row_num,
        row_number() over(partition by reportdate, market, platform order by row_num) rn
    from mytable
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the inputs. I should update mytable with the sum values.
I have cte to get the row_num values and  after that i thought to do sum on cte but i am not sure how to do.
 ;WITH cte_mdl AS 
             (SELECT xx.[reportdate], xx.[market], xx.[platform],xx.[impr], 
     xx.[leads] , xx.create_date,xx.[file_id],
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY xx.market, xx.reportdate,xx.IMP_platform
             ORDER BY xx.[file_id] DESC) row_num FROM    mytable xx
group by xx.[reportdate], xx.[market], xx.[IMP_platform],xx.create_date,xx.[file_id])
 select * from cte_mdl

Comment: @swathi: this is different than the question your originaly asked. I would suggest asking a new question for this, with proper sample data, desired result, and current query.